# handling significant amount of 0 Values in Numerical variables in Linear regression model

Tags: python, linear-regression, outliers

bit new to this but here goes

I have a vehicle FAIL dataset that i want to use to predict Fail rates using some linear regression models

Target Variable is Vehicle FAIL %
14 Independent continuous Variables are vehicle Components Fail %
more than 20 Vehicle Make binary Features, 1 or 0
Approximately 2.5k observations. 70:30 Train:Test Split

My concern is that for Each of the continuous Features the vast majority of Observations would have a value of 0% - A legitimate numerical Value.

However when I look at the outliers for each numerical Variable it is in the hundreds for some of them. i believe because of the aforementioned 0's

Removing the 0 Values would essentially decimate the dataset.

I have split the data and ran linear regressions , Lasso, Ridge, Random Forest etc. Getting good results.

But am concerned that i have missed something here given the outliers. Should i do something with these 0 values - or accept them for what they are. as they are relevant to my model

Any thoughts or guidance would be very appreciated

Thanks

I looked into possibly removing the 0's using

```
zir = ZeroInflatedRegressor(
    classifier=SVC(),
    regressor=LinearRegression()
    )
zir.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But this returned the below error

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets`
```

i know now that this was the wrong approach as i cant use accuracy measure for Linear Model.

Comment: `However when I look at the outliers for each numerical Variable it is in the hundreds for some of them` What do you mean by that? When you say there are lots of outliers, how are you checking for that?

Comment: Hi Nick, i am Calculating Q1, 3 IQR for each Variable  and the UB and LB                                                        
   if j < LB or j>UB Outliers for Column : p.append(round(j,4)

Comment: so for example Outliers for Column :  Chassis and Body %  Outliers count  189

Comment: Then I don't think the zeros are the outliers - e.g. if you have a dataset with 900 zeros and 100 ones, then the Q1 and Q3 are both 0, so the IQR is 0 too. Then the 100 ones are the outlier, not the zeroes. Those outliers might still be meaningful, depending on your problem.

Comment: Thank you Nick - this is my train of thought as well. i may not have articulated this. They are definitely meaningful.

Comment: Oh, I see. How many non-zero values do you have, for each column?

Comment: In the training set of 1750 observations the 0 values range from 200 to almost 1400 for some  variables. So Non zeros anywhere from 350 to 1550 approximately

Comment: 350 non-zero examples is plenty for a linear regression to learn a parameter.